# Linear geometric transformations square

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I have a square (2,2) , (2,4), (4,6), (2,6) and I need to find the new position after rotating this square arount (1,1) with an angle of 120 degree in the anti-clockwise direction.

I would like to know if my reasoning is good.

1. Translate the square by (-1,-1) (A)
2. Rotate about the origin (B)
3. Translate the square by (1,1) to go back at (1,1) (C)

Let define A,B,C the matrix of the operation

So the solution would be C*B*A = D

And I would need to multiplicate each dot by my matrix D.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Do you know the two dimensional rotation matrix? (Brush up on basic trig!) In essence, that is the only matrix you need here

Comment: You may want to check on the coordinates again, [they definitely don't look like a square to me](http://imgur.com/a/dSEsj)

Comment: yes I know it thank you

Comment: @2012ssohn yes thank you are right